# How to use bootstrap checkbox control in django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, python-3.x, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I am using `check box` control in a simple `django` application. When I use the standard `check box` control, I can get the desired values in `views.py`. But I fail to get the values when I use `bootstrap` check box control. Logic seems to be fine, I don't know why it's not working. Can anybody point out the mistake, Thanks in advance.

**Standard Way**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Apple"> Apple 
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Mango"> Mango
```

**Bootstrap Way**

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="fruit">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="fruit">Apple</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="fruit">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="fruit">Mango</label>
</div>
```

**view.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        fruit = request.POST.getlist('fruit')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `id="fruit"` for both and `for="fruit"` for both.

Those need to be different for different checkboxes.

Also, the values were set to empty in your case.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Apple" id="apple">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="apple">Apple</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Mango" id="mango">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="mango">Mango</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made changes as you have mentioned but still it's not working

Comment: Have you set the values for each as well? Your values were empty.

Comment: Ya of course, Same code as you mentioned above. 
fruit = []
  
fruit.append(request.POST.get('apple'))

  fruit.append(request.POST.get('mango'))

Comment: But this: `fruit = request.POST.getlist('fruit')` would also need to be adjusted.

Comment: OK, this is now getting outside the Bootstrap territory. What you have now is working a Bootstrap HTML code. Your next task is to adjust that for Django so that it works there. You may want to post a separate question for that (using the HTML I gave you as a basis).